# How to sorting related articles based on common tags?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an articles and tags table. Every article can have multi tags. I want to get related articles for an article and sort result based on common tags.

```
// Tag Model
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Article::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
// Article Model
class Article extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

I use this code to get related articles but i don't know how to sort result based on more common tags.

```
// And i 
$relatedArticle = Article::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($article){
    $query->whereIn('name', $article->tags->pluck('name'));
})->where('id', '!=', $article->id)->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: I'd do the query from Tag class rather than Article class, `Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->with('articles')->groupBy('tag_name')` - Bare in mind whereHas is slower so I motivate my self not to use it :)

Comment: Thanks. But can you help me to sorting the result based on more common tags please? example, when showing A , B have 3 common tag with  A and C have 4 common tag with A, i want in related result C come before B

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly trying to achieve but do you mean sortBy?

Comment: Yes i mean sortBy, but sort by more related tag, and more related tag is article that have more common tag with current article. sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, the information you want would be retrieved with something like this (I don't know the name of the associative table or the foreign and primary keys, so change that if necessary):

```
SELECT articles.*, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(tags.id)
    FROM tags 
    JOIN articles_tags at ON tags.id = at.tag_id
    WHERE tags.name in ('A', 'B', 'C') /* acquired from $article->tags->pluck('name') */
    AND at.article_id = a.id
) as tags_in_common
FROM articles a 
WHERE articles.id != {$id} 
AND tags_in_common >= 1
ORDER BY tags_in_common DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Now, using queryBuilder, we have to get a bit dirty, but it might look something like this:

```
//Fetches pairs: [article_id, numberInCommon]
$tagsInCommon = DB::table('tags')
    join('articles_tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'articles_tags.tag_id')
    ->select('articles_tags.article_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as numberInCommon'))
    ->whereIn('tags.name', $article->tags->pluck('name'))
    ->groupBy('articles_tags.article_id')

$relatedArticle = Article::
    ->joinSub($tagsInCommon, 'tags_in_common', function($join){
        $join->on('id', '=', 'tags_in_common.article_id')
    })
    ->where('id', '!=', $article->id)
    ->orderBy('tags_in_common.numberInCommon', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```